# C# Send message to SQL Service Broker Queue

Tags: c#, sql, service-broker

I am looking to send messages to the service broker queue via C#. I was sending the command like this:

```
string send = String.Format("BEGIN TRANSACTION; BEGIN DIALOG {0} FROM SERVICE [/AVAILH/xml/InitService] TO SERVICE N'/AVAILH/xml/CreateFile' ON CONTRACT [/AVAILH/xml/Contract] WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF; SEND ON CONVERSATION {0} MESSAGE TYPE [/AVAILH/xml/CreateFile] ({1}); COMMIT TRANSACTION; GO", runID, xmlMessage);

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{ 
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(send, conn))
    {
       conn.Open();
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
});
```

However when this gets called again I get an error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '2'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'(....)

I'm just trying to figure out a simple way to send messages to the queue, which will be happening repeatedly.

*Any help or guidance will be much appreciated!*

Answer (score 4):

```
var sendCmd = @"
    BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

    DECLARE @cid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @xml XML = @message;

/* Begin dialog the conversation id into this variable. */
    BEGIN DIALOG @cid FROM SERVICE [/AVAILH/xml/InitService] 
        TO SERVICE N'/AVAILH/xml/CreateFile' 
        ON CONTRACT [/AVAILH/xml/Contract] 
        WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF; 

    SEND ON CONVERSATION @cid 
        MESSAGE TYPE [/AVAILH/xml/CreateFile] (@xml); 

/* if you don't do this you will have converations open forever unless 
   you clean them up later */
    END CONVERSATION @cid; 

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
";

using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var command = new SqlCommand(sendCmd, conn))
{
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", xmlMessage);
   conn.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If you wish to send more messages on the same conversion instead of `END CONVERSATION @cid` you can so `SELECT @cid` and use `var cid = (Guid)command.ExecuteScalar();`  I'd also suggest moving the `END CONVERSATION` to an internally activated reader when an end or error message is received and to acknowledge the initial message with an `END CONVERSATION` in your reader for the above message.